# Problems installing wquantiles on Windows

Tags: python, pip

Using a Mac, I wrote a package named `game_prediction` found [here](https://github.com/aaronengland/game_predictions). It uses the `wquantiles` package which I have included in the `requirements.txt`. I had no issues pip installing and using this package when using my Mac (Anaconda distribution), however, when using my PC (Anaconda distribution) running `pip install wquantiles` returns the following... `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wquantiles (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for wquantiles`.

[image: Error in command prompt]

I can pip install `wquantiles` using Google Colab. So, I am thinking it must be an issue with PCs? My machine?

I have uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it but am still having the same issue.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is that the complete output or is there more to the error message that `pip install wquantiles` gives you

Comment: @FlyingTeller see the above image

Comment: For one, please don't post error messages as screenshots, always post them by copy pasting them into your question.

Comment: regarding the error: Looks like there is a problem locating the `ssl` module. Since you have anaconda but seem to be using `cmd`, could you try to run `conda activate base` or use the `anaconda command prompt`

Comment: @FlyingTeller using `conda activate base` and then `pip install wquantiles` worked like a charm! Thank you!